# Sequel transactions wrap exceptions instead of reraising them

Tags: ruby, transactions, sequel

When using transactions in Sequel you are supposed to be able to raise an exception and have it bubble out of the transaction block.

From the Sequel documentation:

> If any other exception is raised, the transaction is rolled back, and the exception is raised outside the block:

```
DB.transaction do # BEGIN
  raise ArgumentError
end # ROLLBACK
# ArgumentError raised
```

However, it seems I'm not able to catch the `ArgumentError` since Sequel wraps it in a `Sequel::DatabaseError`:

```
begin
  DB.transaction do
    raise ArgumentError.new('Hey')
  end
rescue => e
  puts e.inspect
  puts e.kind_of?(ArgumentError)
end
```

Result:

```
> #<Sequel::DatabaseError: ArgumentError: Hey>
> false
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Will this work ? `puts e.message['ArgumentError'] == 'ArgumentError'`

Comment: Yes, but it's hacky and if the exception is part of a deep hierarchy it messes up the exception flow so I'd rather avoid that kind of solution.

Comment: Then `puts e.message == 'Hey'`? should work then. It helps you to understand from where the error is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `wrapped_exception` as documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/v/viking-sequel-3.10.0/Sequel/Error.html) and re-raise the exception.

```
begin
  DB.transaction do
    raise ArgumentError.new('Hey')
  end
rescue Sequel::DatabaseError => e
  raise e.wrapped_exception
end
```